# R4.1.0, Windows 10, Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '001.csv': No such file or directory

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am working on a class assignment. The goal is to write a function which reads all files in the subdirectory (named "specdata") and returns the mean value of the data from the chosen column (pollutant).

Here is what I wrote:

```
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id=1:332){
  file_list <- list.files ("specdata")
 main_data <- data.frame()
  for (i in id) {
  main_data <- rbind (main_data, read.csv(file_list[i]))
  }
  result <- mean(main_data[,pollutant])
  return(result)
   }
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:332)
```

and I got an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '001.csv': No such file or directory
```

I have checked the current working directory:

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/pl6z7/Desktop/Coursera"
```

There sure are files in the subdirectory named "specdata".

```
list.files("specdata")
  [1] "001.csv"     "002.csv"     "003.csv"     "004.csv"     "005.csv"     "006.csv"    
  [7] "007.csv"     "008.csv"     "009.csv"     "010.csv"     "011.csv"     "012.csv"    
 [13] "013.csv"     "014.csv"     "015.csv"     "016.csv"     "017.csv"     "018.csv"    
 [19] "019.csv"     "020.csv"    ...
```

I can open the file by using file.choose() and manually selecting the file.

```
read.csv(file.choose())
         Date sulfate nitrate ID
1    1/1/2003      NA      NA  1
2    1/2/2003      NA      NA  1
3    1/3/2003      NA      NA  1
4    1/4/2003      NA      NA  1
5    1/5/2003      NA      NA  1
6    1/6/2003      NA      NA  1
7    1/7/2003      NA      NA  1
....
```

What is the problem here?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just use the argument `full.names = TRUE` in the `list.files`-call and you will never have problems with relative paths. Your working directory is `.../Coursera`, hence R searches for the csv files in this directory (instead of `.../Coursera/specdata`) when you simply use the filenames instead of full file-paths.

Comment: Moreover, there are lot of questions on StackOverflow which has dealt with this specific Coursera course assignment. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+pollutantmean

Comment: Thanks for including lots of code in your question and it's clearly laid out. I'd suggest having a look at this as well if you have more questions like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thank you Jonas for the answer; it helped my to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the other comments as well. I am sorry for posting this question here when this was not the right place to ask about a classwork.  I indeed looked into the other questions on the assignment, but I could not find the one for this particular problem, or could not figure out the solution myself.. I will be more careful about it in the future.